# Error while launching knife configure command

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, knife

I tried to getting started with chef so I installed the chef gem on my laptop ( OS : OSX 10.8) with ruby 2.0.0-p0 but when I try to "knife configure " I juste get this message :

```
/Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:106:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems/format (LoadError)
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:106:in `require'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/provider/package/rubygems.rb:34:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/providers.rb:60:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chefspec-0.9.0/lib/chefspec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chefspec-0.9.0/lib/chef/knife/cookbook_create_specs.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:37:in `load'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:37:in `block in load_commands'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:37:in `each'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:37:in `load_commands'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/knife.rb:119:in `load_commands'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/knife.rb:167:in `run'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:123:in `run'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.4.0/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/bin/knife:23:in `load'
from /Users/maximeheckel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/bin/knife:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The accepted answer isn't entirely correct. The problem isn't ruby 2.0, it's rubygems 2.x. If you run `gem update --system 1.8.25` to downgrade to a pre 2.x rubygems, everything works like a champ.

**NOTE:** I haven't had to do this locally, but this is how I've gotten `knife bootstrap` to work against my remote servers. I'm running ruby 2.0 on my local machine with latest rubygems and chef 11.4.4 and everything else seems to work properly.

Comment: This worked for me, but then later I could not use the pg gem, because pg_ext.so (a native library) is not copied from the ext folder to the lib folder in the gem.  I have never seen this wrong behavior, and can only guess because this version of rubygems isn't fully ruby 2.0.0 ready.  I suspect any native gem will have problems with this workaround.

My workaround was to go back to a 2.x rubygems, and alos use the release candidate of chef (11.6.0.rc.4), which has a fix in chef for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this issue at opscode](http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3933) it was a bug. It has been fixed in chef 11.6.0.

The problem is that only chef 11.4.4 is on rubygems as of today (2013-06-23)

So, either use 1.9.x or rubygems 1.8.25 will work for now, until the next version of chef comes out. It may be possible to build it from https://github.com/opscode/chef.git

I ended up patching my chef 11.4.4 lib/chef/provider/package/rubygems.rb with this file: https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/d6748efde62502ab6f5d97052f46ca00352497ef/lib/chef/provider/package/rubygems.rb

Comment: Thanks - this sorts things for me. In my Gemfile: `gem 'chef', :git => 'https://github.com/opscode/chef.git', :ref => '11.6.0'`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar errors trying to use Chef (10.24 and 11.4) with Ruby 2.0 - so I assume Chef is not yet Ruby 2.0 compatible :(

Comment: I upgraded from 10.24.0 to 10.28.2 and that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is great if you're using the system ruby (/usr/bin/ruby, for example), but it didn't work for me because I'm using RVM. I found [an equivalent solution](http://www.linuxguy.in/solved-cannot-load-such-file-rubygemsformat-loaderror/) in case you're using RVM:

`rvm rubygems 1.8.25` will install rubygems version 1.8.25 for your RVM ruby.